# Randomly generating graph based off number of connections on each node

Tags: graphs, randomized-algorithms

I'm trying to generate a graph based off some data I have.

This graph should have `N` nodes where the number of edges each node has is equal to a random number `P(k)`, where k is the "index" of the node (mostly arbitrary).

My question is, is there an actual way to do this? I'm thinking that I need more data that either determines the density or another degree of connections out (N1->N2->N3), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: What did you try a) using "paper and pencil" to find a solution to a couple of examples yourself b) denoting an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to generate a graph with some degree sequence (which you want to be random, but this is not relevant); this is called the [graph realization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_realization_problem) which is solved e.g. by the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) in the sense that the algorithm will return a (simple) graph with the desired degree sequence if that is possible (such sequences are called *graphic*). Note that not all finite sequences over $\mathbb N$ are graphic as e.g. any sequence whose members sum to an odd number cannot be graphic by the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) (which states that the sum of all degrees in a graph is equal to 2 times the number of edges in a graph and thus even).
Further, the solutions will in general not be unique: The degree sequence $(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$ for example can be realized by the cycle graph $C_6$ of size $6$ or the disjoint union $C_3 \mathop{\dot\cup} C_3$ of two cycle graphs $C_3$ of size $3$ each.

Many graph libraries for programming languages have implementations of algorithms for this problem, for example the Python library [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.degree_seq).